# force json_encode to use same key for all values

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a php array like

```
array("Some Name","Some Othername")
```

i want to have a json object like this

[{"value":"Some Name"},{"value":"Some Othername"}]

what's the solution?!

Comment: JSON doesn't do any handling. You give it what you want, and it outputs it. So: `json_encode(array_map(function($m){return array("value"=>$m);},$input_array));`

Comment: This answer is working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$test = array("Some Name","Some Othername");
$temp = array();
foreach($test as $i=>$k)
{
    $temp[]['value'] = $k;
}
print_r(json_encode($temp));
```

another option:

```
$test = array("Some Name","Some Othername");
echo json_encode(array_map(function($temp){return array("value"=>$temp);},$test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your PHP Array like:

```
array(
  array("value" => "Some Name"),
  array("value" => "Some Othername")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$array1 = array("Some Name","Some Othername");
$arrar2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $value){
   $array2[] = array("value" => $value);
}
echo json_encode($array2);
```